# Cannot GET / node.js error

Tags: javascript, node.js

im making a simple todo list app , but am getting an error Cannot GET /

I think it has something to do with not creating a home route , also there might be a bug in index.ejs , but not sure exactly what it is. Any help is greatly appreciated ! thanks !!

app.js

```
// Dependencies
var express   = require('express'),
   path       = require('path'),
   bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
   mongoose   = require('mongoose'),
   cookieParser   = require('cookie-parser'),
   expressSession = require('express-session'),
   passport       = require('passport'),
   passportLocal  = require('passport-local');

// MongoDB
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/todos');

// Express
var app = express();

// Configuration
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// app.use(cookieParser);
app.use(expressSession({ 
    secret: 'secret-key',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'bower_components')));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));


// Route
app.use('/todo', require('./routes/todo'));
app.use('/', require('./routes/user'));


// Start Server 
app.listen(3000);
console.log('TODO app is running...');
```

routes/user.js

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var router = express.Router(),
    cookieParser   = require('cookie-parser'),
    expressSession = require('express-session'),
    passport       = require('passport'),
    passportLocal  = require('passport-local');


require('../models/user');

var User = mongoose.model('user');

passport.use( new passportLocal.Strategy(function(username, password, done){
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
        console.log(user);
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
      }
      if (user.password != password) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
      }
      return done(null, user);
    });
}));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});

router.get('/login', function(req, res){    
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        res.redirect('/todo');
    }
    res.render('login', { message: req.session.messages });
});


router.post('/login', loginPost);//passport.authenticate('local'), function(req, res){  
//  res.redirect('/todo');
// });
function loginPost(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }

    if (!user) {
      req.session.messages = info.message;
      return res.redirect('/login');
    }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            req.session.messages = "Error";
            return next(err);
        }

      // set the message
      return res.redirect('/todo');
    });

  })(req, res, next);
}

router.get('/logout', function(req, res){
    req.logout();
    req.session.messages = "";
    res.redirect('/login');
});

router.get('/signup', function(req, res){   
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        res.redirect('/todo');
    }
    res.render('signup');
});

router.post('/signup', function(req, res){  
    new User({username: req.body.username, password: req.body.password}).save(function(err, doc){
        if(err) res.json(err);
        else    res.redirect('/login');
    });
});


module.exports = router;
```

routes/todo.js

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var router = express.Router();

require('../models/todo');
require('../models/user');

var todo = mongoose.model('todo');
function isAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    // CHECK THE USER STORED IN SESSION FOR A CUSTOM VARIABLE
    // you can do this however you want with whatever variables you set up
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();

    // IF A USER ISN'T LOGGED IN, THEN REDIRECT THEM SOMEWHERE
    res.redirect('/login');
}

router.get('/', isAuthenticated, function(req, res){
    console.log(req.session.passport.user);
    var User = mongoose.model('user'), userData;
    User.find({ _id: req.session.passport.user}, function(err, user){
        console.log(user);
        userData = user; return true;
    }).limit(1);
    console.log(userData);
    todo.find({user: req.session.passport.user}, function(err, todos){
        res.render('index', {items:todos, userData:userData});
    }); 
});

router.post('/add', function(req, res){
    new todo({task: req.body.task, user: req.session.passport.user}).save(function(err, doc){
            if(err) res.json(err);
            else    res.redirect('/todo');
    });
});

router.get('/delete/:id', function(req, res){
    todo.remove({_id: req.params.id}, function(err){
        res.redirect('/todo');          
    });
});

router.post('/update', function(req, res){
    todo.where({_id: req.body.id}).update({status: req.body.status}, function(err, doc){
            if(err) res.json(err);
            else    res.send(200);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

views/index.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>EHad Todo App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="todo.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class=".col-md-6 .col-md-offset-3">
    <section class="panel tasks-widget">
      <header class="panel-heading">
          <p class="bg-primary"><%= userData[0].username %> Todo list</p>
      </header>
      <div class="panel-body">

          <div class="task-content">

              <ul class="task-list">

                    <% for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) { %>
                        <li class="task-<%= items[i].status %>">
                            <div class="task-checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="task-list-check" value="<%= items[i]._id %>" <% if(items[i].status == 'done'){ %> checked <% }%> >
                            </div>
                          <div class="task-title">
                              <span class="task-title-sp"><%= items[i].task %></span><sub class="date"><%= items[i].date.toDateString() %></sub>
                              <div class="pull-right hidden-phone">
                                  <a href="todo/delete/<%= items[i]._id %>"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">x</i></button></a>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                        </li>
                    <% } %>

              </ul>
          </div>

          <div class=" add-task-row"> 
                <form action="todo/add" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="task" placeholder="ADD Task">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm pull-right">Add New Tasks</button>
                </form>
          </div>

          <span style="font-size:12px"><a href="logout">Logout</a></span>
        <div><p class="bg-info">copyright By @emranulhadi 2015</p></div>
      </div>
  </section>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".btn-danger").on("click", function(e){
            var r = confirm("Are You Sure? You want to DELETE!!!");
                if (r == true) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                }
        });
        $('.task-list-check').click(function() {
            var taskStatus = "done";

            if($(this).is(":checked")){
                $(this).parent().parent().addClass('task-done');
            } else {
                $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('task-done');
                taskStatus = "new";
            }

            $.post( "todo/update", {id: $(this).val(), status: taskStatus}, function( data ) {
                console.log(data);
                return true;
            });
        });
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: exactly. You don't have a `GET /` defined in your `routes/user.js` file.

Answer (score 0):

In your `routes/user.js` file, define another route definition for `/`, and render whatever view you want for the index route.

```
router.get('/', (req, res){
   res.render("/path/to/view/file");
});
```